# How can I get the SUM of a variable from a set of ID numbers? PLSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql, logic

My issue here is that I've got two tables,

```
SQL> select * from paydata1;

IDNO NAME                      J     SALARY      PAYHR
---- ------------------------- - ---------- ----------
1111 Ann French                S      75000          0
2222 Robert Costa              H          0         45
3333 Linda Ames                H          0         50
4444 Scott Brooks              S      78000          0
5555 Susan Ash                 S      57000          0
6666 James Smith               S      55000          0
7777 Mary Jones                H          0         36
8888 John Morse                H          0         39
```

and

```
SQL> select * from paytran1;

IDNO PRO    HOURSWK
---- --- ----------
1111 123         20
1111 456         10
1111 789         15
2222 123         17
2222 456         24
2222 789         20
3333 123         20
3333 789         20
4444 123         10
4444 456         28
4444 789          5

IDNO PRO    HOURSWK
---- --- ----------
5555 456         40
6666 456         44
7777 456         30
7777 789         15
8888 123         10
8888 456         25
8888 789          5
```

MY PL/SQL code here:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
        v_idno  paydata1.idno%TYPE;
        v_name  paydata1.name%TYPE;
        v_jcode paydata1.jobcode%TYPE;
        v_sal   paydata1.salary%TYPE;
        v_payh  paydata1.payhr%TYPE;
        v_hrsw  paytran1.hourswk%TYPE;
        CURSOR curse IS
                SELECT paydata1.idno, name, jobcode, salary, payhr, hourswk
                FROM paydata1, paytran1;
BEGIN
OPEN curse;
FETCH curse INTO v_idno, v_name, v_jcode, v_sal, v_payh, v_hrsw;
WHILE curse%ROWCOUNT < 9 AND curse%FOUND LOOP
        IF v_jcode = 'S' THEN
                v_sal := v_sal / 52;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name || ': weekly salary is ' || v_sal);

        ELSE
                v_hrsw := sum(payhr)
                v_sal := v_payh * v_hrsw;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name || ': overall pay is ' || v_sal);
        END IF;
   FETCH curse INTO v_idno, v_name, v_jcode, v_sal, v_payh, v_hrsw;
END LOOP;
CLOSE curse;
END;
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

I need to be able to divide the employee's where they're salaried, and find the pay per hour multiplied by hours worked (from the second table)
My issue is that in the second table, the hours worked are split into multiple sections. How can I get the sum of the hours worked so I can place it into my variable 'v_hrsw'?

Right now it's only grabbing the first number it finds in paytran1.hourswk to use as v_hrsw.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT:

Outcome looks like this currently...

```
Ann French: weekly salary is 1442.31
Robert Costa: overall pay is 900
Linda Ames: overall pay is 1000
Scott Brooks: weekly salary is 1500
Susan Ash: weekly salary is 1096.15
James Smith: weekly salary is 1057.69
Mary Jones: overall pay is 720
John Morse: overall pay is 780
```

But anyone with "overall pay" has an incorrect total.

Comment: What is your expected output based on 2 tables?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query directly to get your output.

```
    select
      d.name||(case when d.j='S' then ': Weekly salary is ' 
          when d.j='H' then ': overall pay is '
      end)||(case when d.J='S' then d.salary/52 
          when d.j='H' then sum(t.hourswk)*d.payhr
        end)  as output
    from
     paydata1 d inner join paytran1 t
    on d.idno=t.idno
    group by d.idno ,d.name,d.J,d.salary,d.payhr;
```

So you can change your PL/SQL code to

```
declare
cursor curse is 
    select
      d.name||(case when d.j='S' then ': Weekly salary is ' 
          when d.j='H' then ': overall pay is '
      end)||(case when d.J='S' then d.salary/52 
          when d.j='H' then sum(t.hourswk)*d.payhr
        end)  as output
    from
     paydata1 d inner join paytran1 t
    on d.idno=t.idno
    group by d.idno ,d.name,d.J,d.salary,d.payhr;
  begin
  for c1 in curse
  loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c1.output);
 end loop;
 end;
```

Comment: I apologize, I should've been more clear. I need to use PL/SQL code here so I'm able to run it multiple times.

Comment: You can use this query in PL/SQL code as cursor and print the output

Comment: I edited the answer and added the PLSQL block using the query I gave. It would be easier to do it this way.

Comment: Welcome. Please accept the answer so the question could be closed.